# Construction of choice function using powerset axiom: Where am I going wrong?

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

Assume we have a non-empty [indexed family of sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indexed_family) $X \equiv \{ A_i \}_{i \in I}$. Then the [axiom of choice](https://www.reddit.com/r/UFObelievers/comments/hwmjtf/no_longer_in_shadows_pentagons_ufo_unit_will_make/) asserts that there exists a choice function $F: X \rightarrow \cup X$ such that $F(A_i) \in A_i$.

I claim that it is possible to build the choice function using just the [powerset axiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_power_set). Of course this cannot be true because choice is independent of $ZF$. So where am I going wrong?

**Constructing the choice function $F$ using $X \equiv \{ A_i \}_{i \in I}$ and powerset axiom**

1. Given an indexed family of sets $X \equiv \{ A_i \}_{i \in I}$, first make this family unique, by creating a new collection of elements $Y \equiv \cup_{i \in I}\{i\} \times A_i$. This
2. Build the powerset $P = 2^Y$.
3. Filter subsets of the powerset that have a single element $(i, \text{some element in }A_i)$ for each $i \in I$. Formally, create the set:

\begin{align*}
&\operatorname{ChoiceFns} \equiv \{ p \in P : \forall i \in I, \text{there exists a unique $a$ such that $(i, a) \in p$}\} \\
&\operatorname{ChoiceFns} \equiv \{ p \in P : \forall i \in I, (\exists a \in A_i, ((i, a) \in p) \land (\lnot \exists a' \in A_i, a' \neq a \land (i, a') \in p))  \}
\end{align*}

This now gives us a collection of choice functions, since each element $p \in P$ maps  the index $i \in I$ to a unique element $a \in p$?

What am I missing?  How am I able to build a set of choice functions ?

Comment: The statement of AC is not building the set of choice functions, but to show this set is nonempty.

Comment: @user10354138 I see, so it ought to be impossible for me to prove that $\operatorname{ChoiceFns}$ is non-empty inside ZF, I take it?

Comment: IMO the wrong point i step 3: "that have a single element ($i$,**some** element in $A_i$)". If e.g. $A_i = \{ a,b,c \}$ you will have pairs $(i,a)$ and $(i,b)$ and $(i,c)$. How to choose **the** right one ?

Comment: $\{x\in\Bbb R\mid x^2<0\}$ is a very valid definition of a set. But how can you prove it's not empty?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thank you, I now see the problem. Is there a reason you chose that particular set, which cannot be proven to be non-inhabited constructively, and thereby leads to synthetic differential geometry?

Comment: It's just a simple example of a "reasonably definable set" which is actually empty. The point was to demonstrate the issue: reasonable definitions does not imply that there is anything satisfying them.